# Can Visual Studio/SSDT 2017 deploy/publish SQL Database project to SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools

I was able build & publish databases to SQL Server 2014 using VS/SSDT 2015 but after installing VS/SSDT 2017 i'm not able to publish databases to SQL Server 2014.

I believe below error message is deceiving it has to do with compatibility between Visual Studio/SSDT and SQL Server 2014.

Here is the error message.

> Unable to connect to target server. Please verify the connection information such as the server name, login credentials, and firewall rules for the target server.
> Login failed for user

Any thoughts & tricks?

Comment: So I take it you can connect to the database from SSDT. Can you generate a script for the update?

Comment: Error message says unable to connect to target server forget about database

Comment: Sorry, I meant server. So even with a valid connection string SSDT can’t connect to the server? Can you connect from Server Explorer in the same Visual Studio instance?